# Laravel Vue.js Build ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am a beginner of laravel with vue.js. when i run the program i got the error was i attached below along with the screen shot image this is the folder struture.

[image]

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App.vue' in 'F:\xampp\htdocs\blogsa\resources\js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 3:0-28
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/js/routes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/AddPost.vue' in 'F:\xampp\htdocs\blogsa\resources\js'
 @ ./resources/js/routes.js 2:0-47 11:13-20
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

**routes.js**

```
import AllPosts from './components/AllPosts.vue';
import AddPost from './components/AddPost.vue';
import EditPost from './components/EditPost.vue';
 
export const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: AllPosts
    },
    {
        name: 'add',
        path: '/add',
        component: AddPost
    },
    {
        name: 'edit',
        path: '/edit/:id',
        component: EditPost
    }
]
```

Comment: Change the import calls. Your `js/app.js` is referring to `./App.vue` which should be `./components/App.vue`. The second error is because `AddPost.vue` is not in your `components` directory.

Comment: I advice to read the error messages more carefully since I literally just read off the solution :p